# Вывод сообщения алертом информации из консоли

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выходила информация в виде алерта на страницу. Вывести нужно данные, которые совершались до этого и находятся в консоли.

Подскажите, как реализовать данное действие?

**Обновление**

Недостаток знаний вызывает затруднение. Есть готовый код, но как реализовать вывод алертом информации которая в консоли. Ума не приложу как вывести сообщение просчитанной функции в консоли. Если же просто прописываю новую функцию и  ней выжу алерт, то он естественно выводит информацию опять в консоль, а нужно окном в браузере.

Данные берутся из формы ввода, численные значения, затем просчитываются и сортируются. Мне же надо, чтобы выводилась информация просчитанных значений с комментариями в коде.

```
console.log("Сортировка ");
sortirovkaDistancii();
console.log("Сортировка окончена");
otsortirovannieDistancii();
```

И вот нужно вывести функцию  `otsortirovannieDistancii();`

Comment: Тут два вопроса: как вывести алерт (это должно быть просто) и как получить доступ к данным в консоли. Что из этого вызывает затруднения?

Comment: в консоль данные пишет ваш код или какой-то сторонний? Если ваш, то он откуда-то берет эти данные ведь? Вот оттуда же и в алерт их забирайте.

Comment: пожалуй, стоит опубликовать участки кода, которые связаны с выведением данных в консоль. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit]. Про комментарии в коде не понял: вы хотите комментарии использовать как данные?

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что у вас нет доступа к коду, который выводит информацию в консоль либо вы не можете его править.

В данном случае, можно использовать обертку метода `console.log` в которой вы сможете "шпионить" за содержимым консоли.

Сделать это можно, например, так:

```
console.log = (function() {
    var storage = [],
        orig = console.log;

    var log = function() {
        // Сохраняем только переданную строку. При желании, можно либо сохранять все
        // элементы либо повторять форматирование console.log.
        storage.push(arguments[0]);
        orig.apply(console, arguments);
    };

    log.getStorage = function() {
        return storage;
    };

    return log;
})();

console.log('test');
console.log('asd');
console.log('qwe');

alert(console.log.getStorage().join('\n'));
```

Подобный подход реализован в тестовых фреймворках, позволяющих создавать "шпионов". В качестве примера, можно посмотреть на [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/).